# Stopping a cumulative sum in dax

Tags: dax

I have a measure calculating the cumulative sum of sales percentages by customer, based on a ranking (one being the biggest customer). I need to stop the calculation when the sum reach a certain value. The code of the measure is as follows:

```
PC Sales Invoice Value Pareto 2 = 

CALCULATE(
    [PC % Value],
    TOPN(
        [PC Value Ranking],
        ALL(Customers),
        [PC % Value]
        )
)
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks

I've tried using EARLIER but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Well you can check if the value has reached it with a simple IF.

```
PC Sales Invoice Value Pareto 2 = 
VAR _v = 
CALCULATE(
    [PC % Value],
    TOPN(
        [PC Value Ranking],
        ALL(Customers),
        [PC % Value]
        )
)
VAR _threshold = 1
RETURN
IF(_value > _threshold,[ _value)
```

Comment: but it will still evaluates all the rows, i would like to stop the calculation, not checking for all row contexts